# Pandas save tuple as a value in a column

Tags: python, database, pandas

I am working on a DataFrame and I need to save tuple as value in a specific column.

```
df['column'] = (423423,41231,5345)
```

After saving the DataFrame to a .csv if I want to get back the value I can't use the tuple again, because it has been saved as a string.

Is there any way to save a tuple (or also object in general) as a value?

It there any specific function in pandas or other library, which allows to transform the previous tuple (saved as string) as a tuple again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csv cannot store python objects , you should use pickle [`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`read_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html) instead.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)],'B':list('xyz')})
```

---

```
print(df)
           A  B
0  (1, 2, 3)  x
1  (4, 5, 6)  y
2  (7, 8, 9)  z
```

---

```
df.to_pickle('test.pkl')
new_df = pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')
print(new_df)

           A  B
0  (1, 2, 3)  x
1  (4, 5, 6)  y
2  (7, 8, 9)  z

type(new_df.loc[0,'A'])
#tuple
```

For a csv , when you read a csv , the values are returned as a string to which you can apply `ast.literal_eval` like `df['Col_name'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` after importing `ast`